# Picasso is unable to fetch the image from server the image ends with jpg

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to get an image from server that ends with jpg but it looks like Picaso is unable to get them.

I tried fetching png images from server and they jsut worked fine!
I also tried getting the image using Glid but also did not work.
Can you help me guys ??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln0I7.png)

Comment: Did you pass the correct url of image? it seems like this `http://caynoon-preview.website/api/uploads/8739032143716.jpg`.

Comment: Sorry about my late answer.
It was a server side problem.
Thanks by the way!